# subprocess.call exit code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jar, subprocess

I have a use case where I execute a java jar through python subprocess. How can I get to know if the subprocess completed successfully or terminated because of some exception. Subprocess does return an exit code but the jar does not handle returning appropriate exit codes.
Is there some other way to do this?

```
class Test(object):
     #constructor
     .
     .
     def execute(self):
         exit_code = subprocess.call(['jar_path'])
         if not exit_code:
             return True
         else:
             return False
```

Comment: does the jar report correct exceptions to stdout or stderr ?

Comment: yes it does support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say -

> Ques : does the jar report correct exceptions to stdout or stderr ?
>
> Ans : yes it does support.

You can use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) along with [`.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and `subprocess.PIPE` to get the data from `stdout`/`stderr` and parse that appropriately to determine whether there was any exception.

Example -

```
 def execute(self):
     proc = subprocess.Popen(['jar_path'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     pout,perr = proc.communicate()
     if not perr:  #or however you want to check stderr/stdout
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

Comment: will it not make subprocess non blocking if I use Popen  instead of call?

Comment: Well, `.communicate()` is blocking, it would block the process till the `proc` completes.

Comment: I tried with communicate. Both stderr and stdout outputs are being redirected to a file instead of PIPE. Probably because of that pout and perr seems to be none.

Comment: when you directly run that jar file in command line do you get any output in the console?

Comment: yes I do. but now inside Popen I am using file to dump stdout and stderr results. I am getting these log in a file. But pout and perr seems to be null. Is it because I am redirecting the output to a file instead of PIPE?

Comment: yes, if you use `PIPE` only then `pout` / `perr` would be non None.

Comment: if you use a file in `stdout` / `stderr` , the data would only go to that file, and `pout` / `perr` would be None. You should use `PIPE` and then if you want to write it to file as well, then after using `PIPE` write it to file using `pout`/`perr` .

Comment: there might be some error collected in PIPE, but the jar continued its execution and generated some more output in PIPE. In that case the ordering inside log file might be inappropriate since it will be writing all outputs first and then all errors.

Comment: If so, you can write to the log file, and then use `open()` to read from it.

Comment: I have something like this: Output logs --> some error logs --> Output logs. Correct me if I am wrong, if I write pout and perr to a file, all pout will come together and all perr would come together.